# Unable to diplay this Web Part when using a DVWP to display items for a large list

Tags: list-view, xslt, data-view-web-part

I hope someone can help me out with this one. I have a large list that contains about 40 columns and currently holds 33 thousand list items in SharePoint 2010.

One of the columns is used to enter an item quantity, and I am using a DVWP and some XSLT to display a report that sums up the quantity per day. I also have a second DVWP that sums up the quantity by month.

DVWP 1 (Sum by Day)

[image]

DVWP 2 (Sum by Month)

[image]

My problem is that I get the following error message when ever the Sum by Day DVWP shows more than two weeks of data, and the same error when ever the Sum by Month shows two months or more.

[image]

I've tried a few things to fix this and nothing has worked.

1. I've increased the list view threshold
2. I've setup some Indexed Columns (Request Date, Quantity and a few other columns)
3. I've run the powershell to increase the XsltTransformTimeOut all the way up to 15

I should also mention that when working on the DVWP in SharePoint Designer everything renders correctly, for example I can see up to 6 months on the Sum by Month WP. However, I consistently get the error message when I browse to the page.

I'm really stuck on this one and would appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks in Advance everyone.

Jovi

Comment: What error do the logs show for the correlation ID?

Answer (score 0):

have you done the following

- Don't use a Linked Source, but instead use DataSourceMode="CrossList". That way, when you add that 37th or 38th list, it'll just keep on working without any changes. Another benefit is that you can get the XSL working with just one list with DataSourceMode="List" and then once you have things the way you want them, you just switch modes.
- Tick the 'Show with sample data' box in the Common Data View Tasks. SharePoint Designer will then render just sample data without going to the server for the real data while you develop.

link:
http://www.endusersharepoint.com/STP/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1027

Hope it solve the issue